# modifying JSON with subarrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, react-hook-form

I'm having an issue getting my data from my "react-hook-form" web form in the correct format for my api

I'm already cheating by entering in the [] date field of the form which isn't ideal but just trying to get passed this step for now.

I need to send it over like the below DesiredData, basically with array brackets around the entire thing and then the apostrophes  **'**["1-2-2020", "1-3,2020"]**'** for the dates

```
DesiredData:[
{
   name:"bob"
   age:"20"
   dates: ["1-2-2020", "1-3,2020"]
}]
```

```
CurrentData: {
   name:"bob"
   age:"20"
   dates: '["1-2-2020", "1-3,2020"]'
}
```

Comment: `CurrentData.dates` is a string, where is this data coming from that the actual type isn't representative of the data type you want/ expect?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var currentData = {
   name:"bob",
   age:"20",
   dates: '["1-2-2020", "1-3,2020"]'
}

currentData.dates = JSON.parse(currentData.dates)

var desiredData = [currentData];

console.log(desiredData)
```